# having an issue installing the vmware-esx-vib-author-rpm on centos

Tags: vmware

having an issue installing the `vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386.rpm`  on the CentOS 6.2 version , it looks for dependencies which is 64 bit

This is the message I get when I try to install the package:

```
[root@centosvirtual1test ~]# yum install --skip-broken vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Install Process
Examining vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386.rpm: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386
Marking vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vorboss.net
 * extras: mirror.vorboss.net
 * updates: centos.serverspace.co.uk
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.3 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vmware-esx-vib-author.i386 0:5.0.0-0.0.847598 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) for package: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) for package: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) for package: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6()(64bit) for package: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit) for package: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libpthread.so.0()(64bit) for package: vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.0-0.0.847598.i386 from /vmware-esx-vib-author-5.0.
```

Comment: have resolved this one

Comment: Hi ,
  The VIB author only works on SUSE enterprise Linux 11 sp2, and no other versions of Linux, as I tried it on the centos, fedora, and SUSE

please check the requirements to install the VIB author.
You will need the following packages 
Python == 2.6 
Coreutils >= 6.9 
binutils >= 2.17.50
tar >= 1.20 done 
bash >= 3.2 done 
grep >= 2.5
file >= 4.19
sed >= 4.1.5
gzip >= 1.3.5
openssl >= 0.9.8i
zlib >= 1.2.3
python-lxml >= 2.1.2
python-urlgrabber >= 3.9.1
And you can download the SUSE Enterprise Linux server 11 SP2
[link](https://www.suse.com/download-linux/source-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VIB author only works on SUSE enterprise Linux 11 sp2.